# FGallery does not begin in thumbnail view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, thumbnails

What am I doing wrong? FGallery is not starting in thumbnail view?

```
    FotosGalleryViewController *vc = [[FotosGalleryViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:self];
    vc.beginsInThumbnailView = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I turn `showThumbnailViewWithAnimation:BOOL` into a public method and call:

```
[self showThumbnailViewWithAnimation:YES];
```

within the `FGalleryViewController` it works. But it only loads the first two images in thumbnail view, the rest stays gray. Clicking `Close` and `See all` again fixes this and everything works as promised?